# What fantasy race has an affinity for water?

Tags: magic, creature-design

I am designing my own fantasy world.  In it, I am trying to tie various aspects of the world, such as water, fire, life... to a particular race that has a magical affinity for that aspect.  Dwarves for earth, elves for life, etc..  I am struggling with what race to use for water.

I would like to use a fantasy race that modern readers would recognize.  While this means the race will have been used before, the race should not exist in a single, copyrighted IP as that could have legal issues.  If there is no preexisting race, I will invent my own.

The race must not be solely aquatic and must be able to naturally travel over land even if it makes them uncomfortable.  The civilization is responsible for water based trade on the oceans and rivers of the world which rules out mermaids.  Additionally, an over aggressive culture that only fights with land based ones wouldn't work.  I imagine them using boats to transfer goods among the other races and living in a Venice like city.  Very mercantile city with lots of water, canals, and fountains all over.  Their water powers allow them to manipulate currents to travel quickly, even with no wind.  They need to be cunning enough to maintain their monopoly over trade and dedicated enough to prevent any of their race from contracting out to any other as a pilot, and negating their advantage.

Let me know what race could work in this role.  If there aren't any you can think of, trait suggestions for inventing a new race are appreciated.

Comment: If all else fails, you *could* just make your humans more-than-average water affine.

Comment: @MartinBüttner - indeed. Humans usually make good rogue trader and/or pirate sorts. More often in scifi than fantasy, but it should translate well.

Comment: I have a hard time accepting that Dwarves are okay for your Earth affinity and yet Merfolk are not okay for your Water affinity. You won't find a better corollary of "Dwarf is to Earth as ___ is to Water" than Merfolk.

Comment: This sounds like a job for Aquaman. In all seriousness: Lizard people (Age of Wonders does this.)

Comment: This question sounds rather a lot opinion-based to me, but could also be too broad. "What race could work in this role?" appears to open the floodgates (no pun intended) to listing almost every race that has occured in fiction which might fit the criteria, with little on which to judge an answer in order to vote. Two of the existing answers are also effectively list answers.

Comment: As worded I have to agree there seem to be countless (well ok you could probably count them all) options here from all the various fictional universes out there.  The "Must be able to walk on land" inclusion is good, if you could add more requirements like that it would help narrow the focus and make the question more legitimately answerable.

Comment: I have put a [question on meta](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/257/17) about putting this On Hold until we get more details that can allow us to potentially suggest a definitive “best” solution, or *at least* narrow things down. I agree with @James that the “must walk on land” bit is good, but we need more or there are just way too many potential options and no way to say any are better than any others.

Comment: no one said MERMAIDS.

Answer (score 8):

[Nereid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nereid) are an obvious choice.

[Kelpie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelpie) might be an interesting twist

Or you could mix it up with some Weresharks

[Undine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undine_(alchemy)) are an option

And of course [Sirens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_(mythology)) have strong links to the sea

Comment: The Land Shark is considered the cleverest of all sharks. Unlike the Great White shark, which tends to inhabit the waters and harbors of recreational beach areas, the Land Shark may strike at any place, any time. It is capable of disguising its voice, and generally preys on young, single women.

Comment: (knock, knock) Candygram

Answer (score 5):

Naga are sometimes used as such a race. There's variety in how they're implemented:

[The original hinduistic Naga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C4%81ga)

[The dungeon crawl stone soup version](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Naga)

[the world of warcraft version](http://www.wowwiki.com/Naga)

There's also mer-people or mer-men or merfolk as they're sometimes referred to:

[from harry potter](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Merpeople)

[from dungeon crawl](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Mermaid)

And even some other varieties with less overt affinity for the water:

[an invitation for downvotes](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gungan)

[more from star wars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Selkath)

Comment: Argh! Downvote! Downvote!

Comment: Actually merfolk are excluded in the question as he doesn't want primarily aquatic - although I guess if they were able to reform their tail into legs and back again they would work.

Comment: @TimB um downvote because it's mostly links? Should I elaborate on _all_ these? The question is quite broad.

Comment: I didn't actually downvote, I upvoted ;) I was responding to your invitation for downvotes.

Comment: @TimB lol i already forgot I wrote that xD

Comment: Although actually as was just pointed out in the chat really this answer as it stands fails the "link only" test. If you remove the markup the answer becomes meaningless - you can't search for "an invitation for downvotes" and find a suitable creature.

Comment: @ivy_lynx Yes, it is quite broad. Too Broad, in fact; I don’t think we should even attempt to answer such a question until more detail is offered.

Comment: @TimB you can fix the "invitation for downvotes" link risk by adding hover text, so if the link breaks people still know what is being referred to.

Comment: @githubphagocyte This isn't my answer :)

Comment: @githubphagocyte doesn't it show the link url at the bottom of the browser? FF does, not sure about chrome, but it's in the answer's source anyway. Is there quick markdown for that or do you mean `HTML` to add hover text?

Comment: @TimB I know but I mentioned you since it was your point :)

Comment: @ivy_lynx I've added hover text by changing the markdown links - hopefully they are now easier to read while editing too.

Comment: @githubphagocyte Uh thanks, but doesn't that just alias the links? I'm seeing no difference in FF. No problem with the edit, I just don't get it :P

Comment: @ivy_lynx it only affects the readability while editing - it makes no difference to the answer as viewed here. The only difference here is that that one specific link now has "Gungan" as hovertext, for people who don't see a link when hovering.

Comment: @githubphagocyte oh right, good idea - I wanted to use that syntax when I was first figuring out Markdown, but I think I just forgot about it. I'll keep it in mind for the future. TY

Comment: no one said MERMAIDS.

Answer (score 5):

The way I see it, you have three primary options (with each one subdivided into lots of smaller options, because the great thing about mythology is that there's so much of it):

**1) Physiological hybrids** a la centaurs. You have specifically stated you don't want mermaids, but mermaids are traditionally part fish. You could just as easily posit a hybrid with an animal that isn't purely aquatic. From here on in, the sky's the limit. It all depends on how humanoid-seeming you want them to be. Find a marine biology blog and browse until you find something so cool you simply can't pass it up. Alternatively, look around Deviant Art; lots of artists there are fond of reinterpreting mermaids with other animals.

**2) Shapeshifters** with or without an external skin object. This is your basic selkie, who appears entirely human on land, but is able to transform entirely into the body of a seal, typically by wearing a sealskin coat. Then you have your ordinary weres, which have long been expanded from the usual wolf to pretty much any animal under the sun. This gives you an advantage in that they can engage in any activity that humans can, with no need at all to explain how they're capable of it.

**3) Elemental spirits** made of, or with an affinity to, fresh or salt water. Grecian nymphs come in approximately a zillion flavors, including every type of body of water. Oceanids for oceans, limnades for lakes, more generally they can be called naiads or hydriades. Other cultures have other types of water spirits, Lamia and Melusine both come to mind, and undines have already been mentioned. Once again you have a choice of how humanoid you want them to seem. The main disadvantage is that water spirits are much more metaphysical, and if you want your nation of water-dwellers to feel real and physical, more like a species than a mythical creature, that might turn you off.

Answer (score 1):

A few additional ones: Many of these are not as well known so you are free to do things with them.  I really like the idea of focusing on Menehune with Altantean elemeents

**Atlanteans** - (or Brasil Islanders which is simular but more Irish)

Clurichaun - (would be funny... powerful leprechauns who are always drunk)

**Menehune** - (Hawaiian mythology - dwarfs who lived on those islands who ate fish, rode in canoes, etc)

Naiad, Nereid, Neck/Nix, Oceanid, Xana- (types of water nymph/spirits)

Selkie - (shapeshifting seal people)

Tritons - (largely like mermaids but have been reshown to walk on land (such as in board game Small World))

For others you could want [partially humanoid races](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_piscine_and_amphibian_humanoids).  I cannot find any good examples, but it seems like a swamp dwelling people would also work well but there are not many. You may also succeed in using pirates, sailors, fishermen, islanders, or river boat dwellering nomads who are other wise normal humans.